# java regular expression partial replace

Tags: java, regex

I am working with some legacy code that has a static method call which we need to remove from our source tree.

The existing code is as follows:

```
Logger.getInstance(JdkUtil.forceInit(SomeBusiness.class));
```

What we need to end up with is:

```
Logger.getInstance(SomeBusiness.class);
```

I've spent all day today trying to figure out how to do that replacement. Since I have very little experience with regular expressions, I have only been able to come up with a pattern that matches the source string.

The pattern JdkUtil.forceInit([a-zA-Z_0-9]*.class) finds matches on the input string I am providing. I've tested this at https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html

So if anyone can post a Java solution to this, I would really appreciate it.

Below is some Groovy code that I have so far. What I am missing is to how correctly replacement explained above.

```
String source = 'Logger.getInstance(JdkUtil.forceInit(RtpRuleEngineCompiledImpl.class))'
    String regexpPattern = 'JdkUtil.forceInit\\([a-zA-Z_0-9\\)]*.class\\)'

    String replaced = source.replaceFirst(regexpPattern, 'hello')

    println replaced
```

When I run the above code I get the following output:

Logger.getInstance(hello)

Obviously 'hello' is just for testing.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can give me some suggestions.

Comment: We're going to need some more context like fields and constructors of SomeBuisness.class to understand why you can't just use the static reference you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll likely want to do something such as:

```
class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String source = "Logger.getInstance(JdkUtil.forceInit(RtpRuleEngineCompiledImpl.class))";
        String regexpPattern = "JdkUtil.forceInit\\(([a-zA-Z_0-9]*.class)\\)";
        String replaced = source.replaceFirst(regexpPattern, "$1");
        System.out.println(replaced);
    }
}
```

**Result**:

```
Logger.getInstance(RtpRuleEngineCompiledImpl.class)
```

The capture group (`$1`) replaces the entire string which was within the parentheses.

Comment: You can remove those `import` lines. They are not used in the `main()` code.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I'm still trying to understand how this magically works, but at least I have something woking :)

Comment: @user3495734: You’re welcome! Please accept the answer if it solved your issue — cheers!

Comment: I've only posted here twice before including this one. Can you share with me how I can accept the answer?

Comment: @user3495734: When you are the person who posted the question there's an outline of a checkmark underneath the score (upvote/downvote) on each answer, when you click it then it turns green and "accepts" the answer. You also gain reputation for accepting an answer, or if your question gets upvoted.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've checked the check mark and it turned to green. Do you know of a good learning resource for regular expressions in Java?? I'm still trying to understand how your solution works 

Comment: There are tons of good regex learning resources online. I would say start with the [Official Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), or if that's too boring maybe try [Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm) (it's a little less heavy). Another great way to learn is to use a site like [RegEx101](https://regex101.com), since you can play around with the tool interactively and it gives you a summary of what everything is on the right. Hopefully that helps or at least gives you are starting point! :)

Comment: @user3495734: As far as how the pattern works it's pretty simple, whatever is enclosed within parentheses becomes a "capture group". Since you only have one capture group then it is obviously capture group 1 or `$1` (which is the variable where the captured string is stored). When you replace the string that your pattern matched with that group  (`$1`) only that portion of it remains.

Comment: Hi if you happen to still be around, I have another use case that I was wondering if you could help me with.  I have to do the same search and replace that I originally posted, but the dot that precedes the call to forceInit is in new line preceded by any number of tabs or spaces.   I looked into this with the DOTALL switch to the pattern class and also (?s). However I am not having any luck .      Again thanks for originally helping me with this.

Comment: @user3495734: If you can post an example of the string in a comment. Based on what you’ve said though something like the following might work: `[\s\t].\nforceInit\\(([a-zA-Z_0-9]*.class)\\)`

Comment: Hi thank you again for replying. Below is a sample of the source text I would like to replace.           
public static PaymentEventEnum get(int key) {
  return (PaymentEventEnum) getEnum(JdkUtil   .forceInit(PaymentEventEnum.class), key);
 } .                                                                       
I would like to replace the above with . public static PaymentEventEnum get(int key) {
  return (PaymentEventEnum) getEnum(PaymentEventEnum.class), key);
 } . I hope this helps.  Thanks again.

Comment: public static PaymentEventEnum get(int key) {
  return (PaymentEventEnum) getEnum(JdkUtil   .forceInit(PaymentEventEnum.class), key);
 } . Sorry about the formatting in my previous comment. In the above example, you can see that the JdkUtil call to forceInit spans to a new line. Also, there could be spaces or tabs before the forceInit call.